# libtorch: Is writing to non-overlapping slices of a torch::Tensor from different threads safe when using index_put_ method?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, tensor, libtorch

I want to write to different non-overlapping slices of a `torch::Tensor` object by calling libtorch's `index_put_` method from different threads concurrently, i.e. each thread writes to a different part of the tensor. Is this safe without any synchronization (i.e. mutexes)? I cannot find any related documentation.

Comment: Yes it is thread-safe, I don't have documentation either but have done that multiple times sucessfully